# How to batch change all instances of pure CMYK white to a shade darker for printing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk, automation, batch-processing

We are a printing company that transfers RGB to CMYK. However when printing CMYK White comes out as transparent (which makes a lot of our art look...not great). We are handling thousands of designs so we need a way to batch process pdfs in photoshop, changing CMYK (0 0 0 0), to (0 0 0 1%) to prevent unwanted elements suddenly becoming transparent.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: are you printing on atransparent medium?

Comment: There is no white ink used in CMYK printing.  You'd have to print something with opaque white ink before overprinting in CMYK to achieve what you want.

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you want to do that? White will still be transparent.

Comment: Confusing question. "White" in the prepress world means "NO ink," also known as the paper stock on which you are printing showing through. I don't understand at all how adding 1 percent black changes anything. Most presses won't hold a 1 % black screen anyway. Just what are you trying to achieve. Also, a picture would be worth a thousand characters in this case.

Answer (score 1):

- Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> Win to open the **Levels** Window
- Click twice the White Eyedropper to set the CMYK to 0 0 0 1%:

[image]

- Click OK and OK to *Save the new target colors as defaults?*
- Make an action with automatic levels
- Batch all the images using this action.

---

Actually the levels for printing images are:

- Black Eyedropper: H=0, S=0, B=96 to don't get areas *pasted* with ink
- White Eyedropper: H=0, S=0, B=4 to don't get areas free of ink: ink holes (the problem described in the question)

Using just CMYK = 0 0 0 1%, this hole is filled with black ink while setting the white levels eyedropper to 96% brightness get distributed among the printing inks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that if you're processing the pdfs in Photoshop you'll lose all vector information?

Anyway, if that doesn't bother you, you could just make an action which adds a *Solid Color* layer with CMYK(0, 0, 0, 1) and set the *Blend Mode* of the *Solid Color* layer to *Multiply*.

[image]

This will pollute all colors of the artwork with 1% black ink, but it's probably not noticeable. You could even enter the layer's *Layer Style* and set the *Blend If* options to preserve dark tones.

(This seems like a hacky way to operate your printer - there must be some other way to do this.)